# Firebase - additionalInfo.isNewUser always returns "false"

Tags: javascript, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I create new users in Firebase with the Firebase Admin SDK by using Node.js.

This process works well, and I see in my Firebase console the new user who has of course never had a login date ("Angemeldet" in German):
[image: Console]

Now I want to check on iOS-login of the user, whether it is his first login:

```
Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password) { (user, error) in

    if let error = error
    {
        self.errorText = error.localizedDescription
        self.shouldAnimate = false
        return
    }

    guard user != nil else { return }

    if let user = user, let additionalInfo = user.additionalUserInfo {
        print(additionalInfo.isNewUser) // Always "false"
        self.userViewModel.firstLogin()
    }
}
```

additionalInfo.isNewUser seems to be exactly what I need, but it always returns "false".

In Node.js I create users with this command:

```
  await admin.auth().createUser({
  uid: uid.toLowerCase(),
  email: uid.toLowerCase(),
  emailVerified: true,
  password: 'notSetYet',
  disabled: false
})
```

Is this a bug, or what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `isNewUser` property essentially compares the values of [`creationDate`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebaseauth/api/reference/Classes/UserMetadata#/c:objc(cs)FIRUserMetadata(py)creationDate) and [`lastSignInDate`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebaseauth/api/reference/Classes/UserMetadata#lastsignindate) and returns `true` if they are equal. Since your user was created on the server before you sign then in on the client, the timestamps will never be the same and `isNewUser` will always be `false`.

The two main options I can think of are to:

1. Check for a certain range between `lastSignInDate` and `creationDate` where you consider the user to be "new".
2. To store whether you've seen the user before in a cloud database (such as Firebase's Realtime Database or Cloud Firestore) from your Swift code, and check to trigger any "new user" behavior you need.

Comment: Thank you for this information! Would be a great feature if isNewUser would be toggled by the first real login and not by some time comparison. Nevertheless I found a solution thanks to you! :-)